# Using the Indy components, I get "connection closed gracefully" errors, but only on some computers

Tags: c++, smtp, gmail, indy

A product I work on uses the Indy components to send emails. It is developed in RAD Studio XE4 (C++). I am trying to find out why it works on some computers but not on others. Of course, it works on my dev box. On the test box I either get a "connection closed gracefully" message or a socket error 10054.

Both machines are loading the same Indy files. My dev box is running Win 8.1 and the test box is running Win 7, so some of the Windows DLLs are different versions, but I doubt that is the problem.

I wrote a very simple test app, and it exhibits the same behavior.

The SMTP messages on my dev box look like this:

```
S: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP vf11sm8649345igb.20 - gsmtp
C: EHLO ks-sayers-v60
S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [64.132.205.66]
S: 250-SIZE 35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C: EHLO ks-sayers-v60
S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [64.132.205.66]
S: 250-SIZE 35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
```

The SMTP messages on my test box look like this:

```
S: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s19sm631546ign.4 - gsmtp
C: EHLO ks-dsatest-v41
S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [64.132.205.66]
S: 250-SIZE  35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C: QUIT
```

I'm using the same gmail user and password in both tests. I am not sure why my test app is sending a QUIT message on the test box instead of an EHLO.

Any help or ideas what to look at will be greatly appreciated!

RAD Studio XE4

Indy 10.6.0.4975

ssleay32.dll/libeay32.dll are v1.0.0g

Test code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::btnSendClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    IdLogFile1->Active = true;

    try
    {
        try
        {
            IdSMTP1->ConnectTimeout = 30000;
            IdSMTP1->Username = edtFrom->Text;
            IdSMTP1->Password = edtPassword->Text;
            IdMessage1->Recipients->Clear();
            IdMessage1->Recipients->Add();
            IdMessage1->Recipients->Items[0]->Address = edtTo->Text;

            IdSMTP1->Connect();
            if (IdSMTP1->Connected())
            {
                IdSMTP1->Send(IdMessage1);
            }
            LogSmtpSettings();
        }
        catch (Exception & e)
        {
            LogSmtpSettings();
            throw Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdLogFile1->Active = false;
    }
}
```

Here are the properties of the TIdSMTP component:

```
Indy Version:        10.6.0.4975
Host:                smtp.gmail.com
Port:                587
HELO Name:           
Mail Agent:          
IOHandler:           TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
Connection Timeout:  30000
Read Timeout:        -1
Authentication Type: Default
Validate Auth Login: True
Username:            's23ayers@gmail.com'
Use EHLO:            True
TLS:                 Explicit TLS
Use Nagle:           True
Use Pipelining:      True
Use VERP:            False
VERP Delimiters:     none
Intercept:           TIdLogFile
Intercept IsClient:  True
Supports TLS:        True
Last Command Result: Ready to start TLS
```

Comment: I don't know this library, but do you need to check for certificate errors?

Comment: When re-throwing an exception, you should be using `throw;` instead of `throw Exception(e.Message);`.  The latter loses all kinds of useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your test box is sending a `QUIT` command immediately after receiving a `STARTTLS` success reply means the TLS handshake is failing. `TIdSMTP` calls `Disconnect()` on itself before then raising a TLS exception into your code saying that the handshake failed.

Also, you are using an older release of Indy 10. `TIdSMTP` was updated in mid-2014 to no longer send `QUIT` if the TLS handshake fails. You say you are using 10.6.0.4975, the current version (at the time of this writing) is 10.6.2.5339.

Now, as for why the TLS handshake is failing is anyone's guess, since you have not provided any details about your setup to diagnose that issue with.  Maybe you have not configured `TIdSMTP` correctly for TLS.  Maybe you don't have the correct SSL/TLS DLLs installed with your app.  Who knows.  Please provide those details.

Comment: I am traveling today, will get those details to you when I can. I do know that the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files are the same on both boxes.

Comment: The exception I am catching is usually `Connection Closed Gracefully`, but occasionally `Socket Error # 10054  Connection reset by peer.`.

Comment: I've edited my question with the properties of the TIdSMTP component. I noticed that `SupportsTLS==False` after a successful test on my dev box, and that `SupportsTLS==True` when the test fails.

Comment: `SupportsTLS` returns true only if the `EHLO` reply reports the `STARTTLS` capability.  Your dev box reports `SupportsTLS` as false because it is successful completing a `STARTTLS` handshake and issuing a second `EHLO`, resetting `SupportsTLS`. Your test box doesn't make it far enough to send a second `EHLO` because of the TLS handshake failure, so you are seeing the `SupportsTLS` value from the initial `EHLO` before `STARTTLS` is sent.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Any suggestions on how to diagnose the TLS handshake failure? I'm not sure where to look to find the source of the problem. It seems to me that the problem must be on the test box itself. What additional details can I supply?

Comment: You haven't answered my earlier question yet. There is an exception being raised when the TLS handshake fails. What exactly does that exception say? Does it say the SSL library could not be loaded? Does it say the handshake negotiation failed? It makes a difference in how you approach a solution.

Comment: The exceptions that I see either say `Connection Closed Gracefully` or `Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer`. I apologize if I'm not looking in the right place for the info you are requesting.

Comment: I rebuilt my test app with XE7 using Indy v10.6.1.5182 and now I am getting a "SSL is not available on this server" exception error.

Comment: Just saw another thread in which you recommended the use of Wireshark. Will do that next.

Comment: Wireshark did not reveal any errors. I saw in another thread that there is a WhichFailedToLoad() function. I added that to my test app and discovered the ssl/tls DLLs where not loading. I'm not sure why they failed to load, but upgrading them to versions from indy.fulgan.com solved the problem. It could be related to the msvcr100.dll dependency in the DLLs that ship with RAD Studio.

Comment: @steveayers: AFAIK, RADStudio does not ship with any OpenSSL DLLs. There are legal issues regarding their distribution and export across country boundaries. You have to download them yourself, or use the ones pre-installed in the OS.